# How do I select 10 rows from a table for past 2 years in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has close to 9 million+ rows from past 4 years
I need to make a list close to 100 thousand samples from past 2 years.
While doing so I can select X rows from each month starting July 2014.

```
    select distinct tb1.field
    from table1 tb1
    join table2 tb2 
    on tb.field = tb2.field
    where tb1.Date between to_date('1-July-2014','DD-MON-YYYY') and     to_date('8-Aug-2016','DD-MON-YYYY') 
    order by tb1.field
```

Thanks

Comment: What criteria will you use to choose the X rows from each month?

Comment: I can select n rows from top or bottom that does not matter, select let's say 100 rows each month randomly in no particular order.

Comment: Your query shows you know how to do a join. (Perhaps.) The rows are selected randomly, based on the date field which is in tb1 - nothing to do with tb2. The choice of the sample should be done in tb1 before joining. So why is the join relevant? Or is it not?

Comment: The join needs to be just so I am selecting data relevant from tb2 which is derived from tb1-- Tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If table tb1 has a column dt (I hope it's not called DATE, that is a reserved keyword and using it as a column name will most likely result in an error), and if you need, say, 100 purely random rows from each of the last 24 months, you could do something like this. Then you can join the result to other tables if you need to. I assume the other columns in tb1 (or the ones you need for the join) are col1, col2.

```
select col1, col2, dt
from (
        select col1, col2, dt, 
               row_number() over ( partition by trunc(dt, 'mm') 
                                   order by dbms_random.value() 
                                 ) as rn
        from   tb1
        where  dt between add_months(trunc(sysdate), -24) and sysdate
     )
where rn <= 100
;
```

Comment: Thanks Mathguy, this actually gives me the solution I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your SQL example is related to what you are asking for in English...
But you can try something like this:

```
with q1 as ( select trunc(Date, 'month') mth, 
                    min(Date) start_dt, 
                    max(Date) end_dt
             from table1
             where date ...
             group by trunc(Date, 'month')),
     q2 as (select table1.*, 
                   row_number() over (partition by trunc(Date,'month') 
                                      order by [some random column]) seq
       where Date ... )
select q2.*
from q1 
join q2 
  on q2.Date between q1.start_dt and q1.end_dt 
     and q2.seq <= [x]
```